# How can I do both email control and custom domain control with regex?

Tags: regex, forms, validation, email, email-validation

I want to check text which entered form field. Text must be valid email and shouldn't contain specific domain between "@" and "." sign. How can I do this with using regex? For example I want an email that shouldn't contain "test" domain

```
mail@mail => Invalid 
mail@test.com => Invalid (Because contain 'test' domain)
mail@mail.com => Valid
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="email">
    <button type="submit" id="sendMail">Send</button>
</form>
```

I can handle valid email with following pattern:

**JS**

```
const btn = document.getElementById('sendMail');

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

  const emailPtrn = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  const email = document.getElementById('email');

  alert(emailPtrn.test(email.value));

});
```

[JSfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0m8t1cog/3/)

How can I check this with single pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `(?!test\.)` negative look ahead after `@` in your current regex,

```
^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(?!test\.)((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^ This will reject any email if what follows immediately after @ is test.
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDeTdP/1)**

Comment: Thank you Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi

Comment: If I check only "test.com" do I need write (?!test\.com\.) If user write "test.com.de" valid but only write "test.com" is invalid?

Comment: If you only and only want to reject the domain if it is `test.com` but want to allow `test.com.de` then the negative look ahead needs to be `(?!test\.com$)`

Comment: thank you but I could not with this pattern. It reject both .com and com.de

Comment: It works like I wrote above. [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDeTdP/2) Here `(?!test\.com$)` negative look ahead will only reject the text if the domain ends with `test.com` only but will allow `test.com.de`

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrong. It work like a charm. Thank you again.